# How to combine two Python scripts?

Tags: python, list, text-files

I want to combine 2 Python scripts into 1 script as it will be easier to run it. What is the easiest way to do it?

Script 1: opens a text file and writes required strings into an output file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

with open("mylist.txt") as f:
    with open("output1.txt", "w") as f1:
        for line in f:
            if "[Running] groups/" in line or "[FAILED!] groups/" in line:
                f1.write(line)
```

Script 2: opens the text file saved by script 1 and replaces 2 strings with something else and saves the output.

```
infile = "output1.txt"
outfile = "output2.txt"

delete_list = ["[Running]", "[FAILED!]"]
fin = open(infile)
fout = open(outfile, "w+")
for line in fin:
    for word in delete_list:
        line = line.replace(word, "link_to_path")
           fout.write(line)
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

So the script should read the text file, only copy the required strings and then replace them with different strings and save them in a textfile.

Comment: Copy and paste to two into one? Or move all the code into functions, and import both scripts into a third one. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: I wanted to know how to combine them into 1 scripts as it will be more efficient and clean code.

Comment: `with open("mylist.txt") as f, open("output1.txt", "w") as f1:` should save you a lot of trouble :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your code into functions, then use an if __name__ == '__main__' block to run the appropriate methods in the appropriate order. Nothing is changed in the content of the functions below:

```
def create_list():
    with open("mylist.txt") as f:
        with open("output1.txt", "w") as f1:
            for line in f:
                if "[Running] groups/" in line or "[FAILED!] groups/" in line:
                    f1.write(line) 

def modify_list():
    infile = "output1.txt"
    outfile = "output2.txt"

    delete_list = ["[Running]", "[FAILED!]"]
    fin = open(infile)
    fout = open(outfile, "w+")
    for line in fin:
        for word in delete_list:
            line = line.replace(word, "link_to_path")
               fout.write(line)
    fin.close()
    fout.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_list()
    modify_list()
```

If you sometimes need to use a different sequence entirely, but with the same basic operations, you can import your script from another script and run a different combination of functions:

```
import myscript
# this script only creates the list, not modifying it at all

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myscript.create_list()
```

The transformation into functions should make you think about what could be made more flexible in your scripts. Do you need to hardcode "output1.txt" and "output2.txt", for instance? Maybe they could be made parameters of the functions? Then you would be able to, for instance, pass in arguments obtained from the command line. You could then decide the file names when you run your script, rather than when you write it.

The weird-looking "if __name__ == '__main__'" idiom allows you to write a script that can be both run as a program and used as a library. If you run your script as a program, the block runs. If you import it from another script, it doesn't -- thus you can do something else with the basic building blocks you defined in your script instead.

Comment: Thank you for the information but I am getting the following error now: "fin = open(infile) NameError: name 'infile' is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

for more efficient and clean code, you don't need to seperate a part with with 12 lines and 7 lines of code into files!
Implement it in a class for an clean code! Its better than to seperate it. 
If you say no, you can import the another file, for example with `import script2`.
But the code what you import should be a methode or class!

Comment: If that's all the code the op has, there's *absolutely* no reason to create a class for it. Write less classes. One or two functions should be sufficient here.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


delete_list = ["[Running]", "[FAILED!]"]

with open("mylist.txt") as f:
     with open("output1.txt", "w") as f1:
        with open("output2.txt", "w") as f2:
            for line in f:
                 if "[Running] groups/" in line or "[FAILED!] groups/" in line:
                    f1.write(line)
                    for word in delete_list: 
                        line = line.replace(word, "link_to_path")
                    f2.write(line)
```